# Auto-award mechanism for old questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounty

Currently, the auto-award mechanism only takes into account newly created answers, even if the bounty was set to reward an existing answer.

For reward-existing-answer-bounties an existent, accepted answer should receive the auto-award.

Comment: A bounty is normally added *because* the existing answers aren't satisfactory.

Comment: If you're absolutely determined to award it to a certain answer - is there anything stopping you setting a reminder for 24 hours time (or is it 48) and just awarding it instead of relying on the system?

Comment: @JonClements: Now that I know, no.

Comment: @jhpratt: There is an explicit option to award existing answers. Please check it.

Answer (score 3):

Some statistics on this are super useful here:

- **4,202** bounties have been created using the "Reward Existing Answer" reason.
- **2,903** of those were awarded to answers which are currently accepted.
- **1,289** of those were awarded to answers which are *not* currently accepted.

That data is still inaccurate. I only looked at the *current* accepted status of answers, and not whether the answer was accepted at the time the bounty was awarded. But still, around 30% of those bounties are not actually intended for accepted answers.

On top of that, there are another **289** bounties that were awarded by the Community user, with a split of 169 of them going to accepted answers and 130 going to non-accepted answers.

So looking at the data, this change will have very minimal impact. You're talking about a whopping **130** bounties that would have ever had a different outcome based on a new rule to award them to an accepted answer automatically.

Given the following things we can see:

- Users are already pretty good at awarding this particular bounty on their own, and don't need the system to do it for them in most cases.
- The change you suggest would result in only a 70% accuracy of what the user might have desired when they started the bounty.

The change doesn't seem like something we should really bother with implementing.

Comment: I've always thought of it as bounties were by design meant to be manually awarded and the auto-award was just something to try and avoid complete wastage if possible.